# Rules: Do action on the field of referenced node

Tags: 7, rules, entities, nodes

I have an "Authors" Content-type, that users can add to their "Article" node while adding a new content as Co-Authors.

Note that it's a seperate content-type not users.

in "Authors" content-type I have an "Email field" which contains the email of the co-author.

What I want to do is using rules, send an email to the `referenced node's email field`

I juggled around in rules but couldn't really make it work, I'd really appreciate a step-by-step process of rules to achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your rule is set to **React on event**: `Before saving content` or `After saving new content` of type `Article`, then do this:

Add condition: **Entity has field**

**ENTITY**: `node:field-your_reference_field`

**FIELD**: `field_email`

This makes the referenced node's email field available in to Actions. So then you can

Add action: **Send email**

**To**: `node:field-your_reference_field:field_email`

This should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works fine, but there's another issue which is that the referenced field can have multiple values, while I'm adding the field it asks for node:referenced-author:0 or 1 and 2 3 4, so I guess it works for just one user, I'd appreciate it if you can guide me how to fix this

Comment: Sure, you should be able to do this within a Rules Loop. + Add loop and then for the list item choose your field and then create your send email action inside of the loop.