# How to access the value of a referenced node's field to use it as a Rules action?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, nodes

I have a content type A that has a node reference to type B.  Type B has an email address field that I would like to use in a Rules Action.  How do I get the value of a referenced node's fields?

**Note**: After much searching, I tried the steps Link suggested in [Rules: Do action on the field of referenced node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126268/rules-do-action-on-the-field-of-referenced-node), but after adding the Entity has Field condition on my node reference field, there are not any replacement patterns like `node:node_reference:field_email`, just the normal `node:field_email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a Rules Action (as the very first action) like "*Fetch entity by id*", which in your case is probably something like `node:node_reference:nid`.

This should make the data available from the node that is referenced via your node reference field.